# PowerShell and RegEx formatting

Tags: regex, powershell

**::EDIT::**

After much goofing off, I was able to find a solution that appears to work in all cases... Consider the following:

```
$subject = '"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,14,80,64,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,02,00,1C,00,01,00,00,00,11,00,14,00,04,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,10,00,10,00,00,02,00,34,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,0B,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,0F,02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0B,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00'

$result = $subject -creplace '(?ism)(.{1,76},)(.{1,75})', @'
$1\
  $2\

'@
Write-Host $result
```

**Note** - Line 6 contains 2 spaces to get the indenting correctly.

This outputs exactly how I need!  Thanks Fede for putting me on the right track!

**Preface:**  I do realize there are other ways of achieving the end goal here, but within my current, larger scope, I need to format $subject in a specific way.

Good evening!  Regex noob here.  I'm attempting to find a way to format $subject in such a way that it is valid for dropping into a Windows .Reg file.  At this point with the code below, I am able to return the first line exactly as I need it, but I'm struggling with trying to figure out how to create a second capture group that returns the values immediately after the first capture group.

Below is my current PowerShell code.

```
$subject = '"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,14,80,64,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,02,00,1C,00,01,00,00,00,11,00,14,00,04,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,10,00,10,00,00,02,00,34,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,0B,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,0F,02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0B,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00'

$result = $subject -creplace '(?ism)(.{1,78},).*', '$1\'

Write-Host $result
```

This returns a $result of:

```
"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,14,80,64,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,\
```

From that point, I need to figure out how to create a second capture group so that it contains the remainder of the hex pairs that I can then apply additional formatting to.

The end goal is to have $result returned like this(for any similar value fed in via $subject):

```
"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,14,80,64,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,\
  00,00,02,00,1c,00,01,00,00,00,11,00,14,00,04,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  10,00,10,00,00,02,00,34,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0b,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,0b,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,0f,03,\
  00,00,00,00,10,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,\
  00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if this is what you want.

Using this regex:

```
(.{1,78},)(.{1,78})
```

You can check this **[working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qQ5kO0/2)**

[image]

Comment: Fairly close.  I had tried the same as well but still couldn't get it to format exactly how I need it to.  Appreciate your time though.

Comment: Super close, problem is from here that lines 2-5 contain 26 hex pairs, and I need it so that each line after the first contains a maximum of 25, if that makes sense.

Comment: @jj1985 glad to help you. Setting 25 pairs instead of 26 is up to you, you only need to use the same regex and changing the max allowed in the braces. If my answer helped you to answer your question you may consider mark the question as resolved or up vote :)